# What do I delete to "de-SourceSafe" a project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

Long story short, I've got a bunch of Visual Studio projects under SourceSafe's "control", and I'm moving over to something that actually works.

When I get a project out from SourceSafe, there are a bunch of other files there, which I assume are just for SourceSafe's convenience.

I believe these are:

SCC files

VSPSCC files

VSSSCC files

Can I just indiscriminately delete files of this type from all of my working directories, or is there anything more/safer I should be doing to cleanse and purify my source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually open the folder in windows. Search for *SCC*, delete all the files. Then open the solution and you should get an error message saying the solution bindings could not be found. You then click permanently remove bindings.

Answer (score 1):

For VS2005 and later, did you try `File->Source Control->Change Source Control`, and then `Unbind`?   That should remove all ancillary SCC files involved.